# Create a DIV within a parent DIV before another child DIV

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to make to make this simpler?

```
$('#content').append('<div id="bar"></div>');
$('#bar').insertBefore('#footer');
$('#foo').appendTo('#bar');
```

This is what the final product looks like, but I am assuming there is cleaner way to do so.

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="bar">
     <div id="foo"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

...well, I got it down to two lines.

```
$('<div id="bar"></div>').insertBefore('#footer');
$('#foo').appendTo('#bar');
```

There really wasn't a reason to append to the #content since the #footer will always be there.

Comment: I don't think [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) does what you *think* it does; in your usage it will insert the `$('#bar')` before the `$('#footer')` element as a sibling. Whereas your finished code suggests that `#bar` should be the *parent* of `#footer`.

Comment: Thanks, just caught that. Let me update the example. Okay updated. My mistake in replicating the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest:

```
$('<div id="bar" />').insertBefore($('#footer')).append('<div id="foo" />');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g8cZx/1/).

While this wins, perhaps, for brevity (and, to be honest, I find it fairly simple to read and understand), I'm not sure it's significantly more-simple than your own first attempt.

I am, in the above code, assuming that the `#foo` `div` doesn't already-exist on the page. If it *does* exist already, then instead use:

```
$('<div id="bar" />').insertBefore($('#footer')).append($('#foo'));​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g8cZx/2/).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Although my solution worked, it was a rough cut. You are right, the 'foo' is dynamic SEO content loaded into the header, but needed to move it into a template page. This is a perfect solution. Thanks for your guidance.